# Writing and reading bytearray on the COM port

Tags: python, serial-port, rs485

I am currently writing a python script to communicate with a pressure regulator in rs485 via the COM port.
I can read its internal variables and write into its variables but if I write into one of its variables and then read a variable, it will always give me 0xff (255) as an answer whatever the variable is...
If I restart my script and I don't write to the variables I can read as much as I want with the right values each time in response.

I don't understand why this happens, can someone help me?

Here is the script:

```
from PyCRC.CRCCCITT import CRCCCITT #Librairie pour calcul du CRC (modifiée)
import serial           # import du module serial pour la communication série
readChoice = 'o'


########################################### FONCTIONS ###########################################

def serial_init():              # initialise les paramètres de la communication avec serial
    global ComPort
    ComPort = serial.Serial('COM3') # Ouvre le COM 3
    ComPort.baudrate = 9600 # initialise le baud rate à 9600
    ComPort.bytesize = 8    # Nombre de bits pour les data = 8
    ComPort.parity   = 'N'  # Pas de parité
    ComPort.stopbits = 1    # Nombre de bits pour le stop = 1
    serial.Serial.TimeoutError = 1  # Timeout
    
    
def menu():                     # affiche le menu et lis le choix de l'utilisateur
    global readChoice
    print("\n\n//////////////////////////////////////////////////")     # Menu
    print("// Voulez vous lire un registre ?  : r          //")
    print("// Voulez vous ecrire dans un registre ?  : w   //")
    print("// Voulez vous quitter ? : q                    //")
    print("//////////////////////////////////////////////////")
    readChoice = input()    # Lecture du choix


def data_to_string(data):       # renvoie une chaine contenant les valeurs hexa de data pour faciliter l'affichage
    s=""                        # var avec chaine de carac
    for d in data:              # d parcourt le tableau data
        s+=hex(d)[2:]           # on slice pour se débarasser du 0x
        s+=' '                  # Rajoute un espace entre les valeurs pour la lisibilité
        
#   s="0x"+s                    # rajoute 0x au début
    return s                    # notre fonction renverra la chaine s contenant nos valeurs hexa


def crc_calc():                 # calcule le crc en fonction de "data" puis rajoute ce crc à la fin de "data"
    global data
    print(CRCCCITT().calculate(bytes(data)))    # calcul du CRC (sur 2 octet donc je le coupe en 2 pour le répartir comme pour les deux octets de valeur à écrire décris plus haut)
    print(hex(CRCCCITT().calculate(bytes(data))))
    crc1 = '0x'+hex(CRCCCITT().calculate(bytes(data)))[2:4]
    crc2 = '0x'+hex(CRCCCITT().calculate(bytes(data)))[4:]
    print(crc1+'\n'+crc2)

    data.extend(bytearray([int(crc1, 16)]))     # on rajoute le crc dans data
    data.extend(bytearray([int(crc2, 16)]))
    
    
def read_command():             # permet d'envoyer une commande demandant à l'ER5000 pour lire une de ses var d'index puis de lire sa réponse
    global data
    global ComPort
    
    print("\nQuel registre voulez-vous lire ?")
    choice = input()
    data = switch[choice]                      # on choisis la commande adéquate dans le dictionnaire switch
    
    ComPort.write(data)                        # écris data sur le COM3 affin d'envoyer notre commande
    print("\nEnvoyé :",data_to_string(data))   # print ce qui a été envoyé pour vérifier avec une fonction transformant data en chaine pour une bonne lecture (faire un simple print de data affiche parfois des caractères ASCII à la place de la valeure correspondante en hexa)
    
    dataIn = ComPort.read(6)                # lire data sur le com (6 octets)
    print("Recu :",data_to_string(dataIn))  # print les data recus après les avoir convertis en une chaine pour faciliter l affichage
    print("Recu brut :",dataIn)

    if dataIn[2] < 10 :                     # Si la valeur de la case 2 dans dataIn est plus petit que 10 (elle va de 0 à F)
        val1 = '0' + hex(dataIn[2])[2:]     # Ajouter un 0 devant la valeur en hexa (sans le 0x en faisant un slice) et stocker le tout dans val1 afin qu elle fasse tjs 2 carac (ex: f -> 0f)
    
    if dataIn[3] < 10 :                     # Pareil pour la case 3 puisque la valeur est stoquée en case 2 et 3
        val2 = '0' + hex(dataIn[3])[2:]
    
    if dataIn[2] >= 10 :
        val1 = hex(dataIn[2])[2:]
    
    if dataIn[3] >= 10 :
        val2 = hex(dataIn[3])[2:]

    x = '0x'+val1+val2                      # Pour écrire la valeur en décimal, j'en fais une valeur Hex reconnaisable par python
    y = int(x,16)                           # Je transforme cette valeur en décimal
    print("Valeur hex recue :", x)          # J'affiche la valeure en hexa
    print('Valeur recue en decimal :', y)   # J'affiche la valeure en decimal
    
    
def write_command():            # permet de calculer puis d'envoyer une commande pour écrire dans une var de l'index du ER5000
    global data
    
    print("\nN° du registre dans lequel ecrire :")
    inReg = int(input())                            # on récupère en int le numéro du registre dans lequel écrire
    
    if inReg == 37:                                 # si on veut changer le setpoint (index 37)
        print("\nEntrez une valeur en mBar")
        inValW = hex(int(convert_mbar_to_val()))    # convertit la valeur entrée en mBar en une valeur equivalente pour le ER5000
        
    else:
        print("\nValeur à écrire :")
        inValW = hex(int(input()))                      # on récupère en hexa la valeur à écrire
        
    data = bytearray(b'\xfa\x04\x01')               # on met déjà le début de la requete dans data car ce morceau sera tjs le même (adresse\longueur\commande "écrire")
    data.extend(bytearray([inReg]))                 # avec un extend on rajoute le numéro de registre entré par l'utilisateur

    if int(inValW, 16) < 256:                       # si la valeur hex va de 0x00 à 0xff alors il y aura 2 cara sur 4 a mettre donc je remplis le premier octet avec 00
        data.extend(bytearray([0]))                 # la commande "bytearray([0])" renverras "bytearray(b'\x00')", on l'ajoute à data pour remplir le premier des deux octets de valeur puisque ici la valeur est <= à FF
        data.extend(bytearray([int(inValW, 16)]))   # on rajoute la valeur entrée par l utilisateur à data

    elif 255 < int(inValW, 16) < 4096:  # si elle est comprise entre 0x100 et 0xfff alors il y a 3 carac a mettre sur 4 donc je sépare en deux et répartis dans les 2 octets
        a = str(inValW)[:3]             # on slice la valeur pour stocker uniquement le 1er carac précédé de 0x dans "a"
        b = '0x'+str(inValW)[3:]        # on slice la valeur pour stocker uniquement les deux derniers carac dans "b" tout en rajoutant "0x" au début pour qu'il apparaisse sous la forme hexa 0x00
        print(a+"\n"+b)                 # maintenant la valeur est séparée de sorte que si la valeur de base était "0xf2a", a contiendra "0xf" et b contiendra "0x2a"

        data.extend(bytearray([int(a, 16)]))    # on rajoute a et b à data, ainsi en reprenant l'exemple précédent on l'aura prolongé de sorte : "\x0f\x2a"
        data.extend(bytearray([int(b, 16)]))

    else:                               # sinon, elle est supérieur et donc les deux octets sont pleins et je le coupe en deux pour le mettre dans les deux octets
        a = str(inValW)[:3]             # meme logique que pour le précédent
        b = '0x'+str(inValW)[3:]
        print(a+"\n"+b)

        data.extend(bytearray([int(a)]))
        data.extend(bytearray([int(b)]))

    crc_calc()

    ComPort.write(data)                        # écris data sur le COM3 affin d'envoyer notre commande
    print("\nEnvoyé :",data_to_string(data))        # print ce qui a été envoyé pour vérifier avec une fonction transformant data en chaine pour une bonne lecture (faire un simple print de data affiche parfois des caractères ASCII à la place de la valeure correspondante en hexa)
    
    

def convert_mbar_to_val():      # convertis une valeur entrée par l utilisateur de mBar à valeur équivalente pour l'ER5000
    mbar = int(input())
    val_mbar = (mbar * 11 + 8000)/20
    return val_mbar
    


########################################### Dictionary ###########################################    

# Dans le dictionnaire, en fin de commentaire, |V| : Renvoie une valeure sencée
#                                              |?| : Renvoie une valeure dont je ne sais pas ou ne suis pas certain de sa pertinence
#                                              |!| : Renvoie une valeure incohérente ou abérante
#                                              |o| : Pas encore testé

# commandes de lecture :
switch = {      # dictionary of read commands (a sort of switch)
    '1' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x01\x6b\x05'),   # Command "Read Index 01" (What is your ID_AD_SETPOINT ? 0 - 65535)          |V|
    '3' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x03\x4b\x47'),   # Command "Read Index 03" (What is your ID_INNER_D_COEF1 ? -32768 - 32767)   |V|
    '5' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x05\x2b\x81'),   # Command "Read Index 05" (What is your ID_COMPENS_EXT_SENSOR ? 0 - 65535)   |V|
    '6' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x06\x1b\xe2'),   # Command "Read Index 06" (What is your ID_COMPENS_INTERN_SENS ? 0 - 65535)  |V|
    '9' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x09\xea\x0d'),   # Command "Read Index 09" (What is your ID_CONTROL_MODE ? 0 - 3)             |V|
    '12' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x0c\xba\xa8'),  # Command "Read Index 12" (What is your ID_PWM_SHUTOFF_FLAG ? 0 - 1)         |V|
    '13' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x0d\xaa\x89'),  # Command "Read Index 13" (What is your ID_RTTASK_DELAY ? 0 - 65535)         |o|
    '16' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x10\x69\x15'),  # Command "Read Index 16" (What is your ID_OUT_D_COEF1 ? -32768 - 32767)     |o|
    '19' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x13\x59\x76'),  # Command "Read Index 19" (What is your ID_INNER_SENSOR_MIN ? 0 - 4095)      |o|
    '20' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x14\x29\x91'),  # Command "Read Index 20" (What is your ID_INNER_SENSOR_MAX ? 0 - 4095)      |o|
    '21' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x15\x39\xb0'),  # Command "Read Index 21" (What is your ID_OUT_INTEG_CONST ? -32768 - 32767) |o|
    '22' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x16\x09\xd3'),  # Command "Read Index 22" (What is your ID_OUT_INTEG_MAX ? -32768 - 32767)   |o|
    '23' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x17\x19\xf2'),  # Command "Read Index 23" (What is your ID_OUT_INTEG_SUM ? -32768 - 32767)   |o|
    '25' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x19\xf8\x3c'),  # Command "Read Index 25" (What is your ID_OUT_PROP_CONST ? -32768 - 32767)  |o|
    '28' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x1c\xa8\x99'),  # Command "Read Index 28" (What is your ID_IN_INTEG_CONST ? -32768 - 32767)  |o|
    '29' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x1d\xb8\xb8'),  # Command "Read Index 29" (What is your ID_IN_INTEG_MAX ? -32768 - 32767)    |o|
    '30' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x1e\x88\xdb'),  # Command "Read Index 30" (What is your ID_IN_INTEG_SUM ? -32768 - 32767)    |o|
    '34' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x22\x7f\x04'),  # Command "Read Index 34" (What is your ID_OUTPUT ? -32768 - 32767)          |o|
    '35' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x23\x6f\x25'),  # Command "Read Index 35" (What is your ID_IN_PROPOR_CONST ? -32768 - 32767) |o|
    '37' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x25\x0f\xe3'),  # Command "Read Index 37" (What is your ID Setpoint ? 0 - 4095)              |V|
    '39' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x27\x2f\xa1'),  # Command "Read Index 39" (What is your ID_GAIN ? 0 - 65535)                 |o|
    '40' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x28\xde\x4e'),  # Command "Read Index 40" (What is your ID_OSET ? 0 - 65535)                 |o|
    '42' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x2a\xfe\x0c'),  # Command "Read Index 42" (What is your adress ? 0 - 250)                    |V|
    '43' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x2b\xee\x2d'),  # Command "Read Index 43" (What is your ID Setpoint Flag ? 0 - 4)            |o|
    '44' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x2c\x9e\xca'),  # Command "Read Index 44" (What is your ID Feedback ? 0 - 4095)              |V|
    '45' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x2d\x8e\xeb'),  # Command "Read Index 45" (What is your ID_PROFILE_LOOP_COUNT ? 0 - 30000)   |o|
    '46' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x2e\xbe\x88'),  # Command "Read Index 46" (What is your ID_SOLENOID_DIRECTION ? 0 - 1)       |o|
    '47' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x2f\xae\xa9'),  # Command "Read Index 47" (What is your ID_MIN_INLET ? 0 - 250)              |o|
    '48' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x30\x4d\x77'),  # Command "Read Index 48" (What is your ID_MIN_EXHAUST ? 0 - 250)            |o|
    '49' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x31\x5d\x56'),  # Command "Read Index 49" (What is your ID_OUT_INTEG_MIN ? -32768 - 32767)   |o|
    '50' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x32\x6d\x35'),  # Command "Read Index 50" (What is your ID_IN_INTEG_MIN ? -32768 - 32767)    |o|
    '52' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x34\x0d\xf3'),  # Command "Read Index 52" (What is your ID_SERIAL_NUMBER ? 0 - 65535)        |o|
    '53' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x35\x1d\xd2'),  # Command "Read Index 53" (What is your ID_VERSION_NUMBER ? 0 - 65535)       |o|
    '64' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x40\x33\xe0'),  # Command "Read Index 64" (What is your ID_PWM_ CONTROL_LIMIT_STATE ? 0 - 3) |o|
    '65' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x41\x23\xc1'),  # Command "Read Index 65" (What is your ID_PWM_VALUE ? -250 - 250)           |o|
    '66' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x42\x13\xa2'),  # Command "Read Index 66" (What is your ID_IN_INTEG_DEADBAND ? 0 - 4095)     |o|
    '67' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x43\x03\x83'),  # Command "Read Index 67" (What is your ID_OUT_INTEG_DEADBAND ? 0 - 4095)    |o|
    '69' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x45\x63\x45'),  # Command "Read Index 69" (What is your ID_PROFILE_TYPE ? 0 - 11)            |o|
    '70' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x46\x53\x26'),  # Command "Read Index 70" (What is your ID_PROFILE_STATE ? 0 - 2)            |o|
    '71' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x47\x43\x07'),  # Command "Read Index 71" (What is your ID_PROFILE_STEP ? 0 - 31)            |o|
    '73' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x49\xa2\xc9'),  # Command "Read Index 73" (What is your ID_PULSE ? 1798 - 2298)              |o|
    '77' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x4d\xe2\x4d'),  # Command "Read Index 77" (What is your ID_COMPENS_EXTRA_AD1 ? 0 - 65535)    |o|
    '78' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x4e\xd2\x2e'),  # Command "Read Index 78" (What is your ID_COMPENS_EXTRA_AD2 ? 0 - 65535)    |o|
    '81' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x51\x31\xf0'),  # Command "Read Index 81" (What is your ID_PULSE_PERIOD ? 0 - 200)           |o|
    '82' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x52\x01\x93'),  # Command "Read Index 82" (What is your ID_PULSE_WIDTH ? 0- 250)             |o|
    '83' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x53\x11\xb2'),  # Command "Read Index 83" (What is your ID_PULSE_DEADBAND ? 0 - 330)         |o|
    '84' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x54\x61\x55'),  # Command "Read Index 84" (What is your ID_PULSE_ENABLE ? 0 - 1)             |o|
    '85' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x55\x71\x74'),  # Command "Read Index 85" (What is your ID_AD_EXTRA1_TOGGLE ? 0 - 4095)      |o|
    '86' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x56\x41\x17'),  # Command "Read Index 86" (What is your ID_AD_EXTRA2_TOGGLE ? 0 - 4095)      |o|
    '87' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x57\x51\x36'),  # Command "Read Index 87" (What is your ID_EXT_FEEDBACK_SOURCE ? 0 - 1)      |o|
    '88' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x58\xa0\xd9'),  # Command "Read Index 88" (What is your ID_DIGITAL_OUTPUT1 ? 0 - 1)          |o|
    '89' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x59\xb0\xf8'),  # Command "Read Index 89" (What is your ID_DIGITAL_OUTPUT2 ? 0 - 1)          |o|
    '90' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x5a\x80\x9b'),  # Command "Read Index 90" (What is your ID_DIGITAL_OUT1_INIT ? 0 - 1)        |o|
    '91' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x5b\x90\xba'),  # Command "Read Index 91" (What is your ID_DIGITAL_OUT2_INIT ? 0 - 1)        |o|
    '92' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x5c\xe0\x5d'),  # Command "Read Index 92" (What is your ID_DA_ANALOG_OUT ? 0 - 4095)         |o|
    '93' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x5d\xf0\x7c'),  # Command "Read Index 93" (What is your ID_TTL_ERR0 ? 0 - 4095)              |o|
    '94' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x5e\xc0\x1f'),  # Command "Read Index 94" (What is your ID_TTL_ERR4095 ? 0 - 4095)           |o|
    '96' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x60\x17\x82'),  # Command "Read Index 96" (What is your ID_TTL_FLAG ? 0 - 1)                 |o|
    '119' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x77\x75\x54'), # Command "Read Index 119" (What is your ID_PROFILE_STARTRUN ? 0 - 1)        |o|
    '120' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x78\x84\xbb'), # Command "Read Index 120" (What is your ID_MODE_ER3000_ER5000 ? 0 - 1)      |V|
    '121' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x79\x94\x9a'), # Command "Read Index 121" (What is your ID_SUSPEND ? 0 - 1)                 |o|
    '122' : bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x7A\xa4\xf9'), # Command "Read Index 122" (What is your ID_SETPONT_RESET ? 0 - 1)           |o|
}


########################################### MAIN PROGRAM ###########################################

serial_init()

while 1:        # Boucle du programme
    
    menu()      # Affiche le menu et permet le choix
    
    
    if readChoice == 'q':   # Si on choisis de quitter
        break               # Sortir de la boucle
    
    if readChoice == 'r':   # si on choisis de lire
        read_command()      # pour lire un index
        
    if readChoice == 'w':   # si on choisis d'écrire
        write_command()     # pour créer la commande d'écriture
        
        
    ComPort.flush()         # nettoie le port


ComPort.close()         # ferme le port

print('\n|fin|')                # ecris "fin" pour confirmer que le programme s'arret.
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it didn't work.
What I read after I write is simply the response from the pressure regulator to confirm that it has received the write request.